# Embedded images in email not showing (.NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, alternateview

In .NET/C# 3.5 I build an email with **embedded images**, receives the email in **smtp4dev** (http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) but the images won't show.
*I use the HTML Agility Pack to parse a HTML document and do some cleaning (this part works fine).*

```
//uninteresting code above

    var images = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img");

    List<MemoryStream> listOfStreams = new List<MemoryStream>();
    List<string> listOfCid = new List<string>();
    List<string> listOfReplacedSrcValues = new List<string>();

            foreach (var img in images)
            {
                var src = img.Attributes["src"];
                if (src != null && src.Value.StartsWith("http://"))
                {
                    listOfReplacedSrcValues.Add(src.Value);
                    //I build a string that looks like this inv_brandLogo_fr_gif
                    string cid = src.Value.Substring(src.Value.LastIndexOf('/'), src.Value.Length - src.Value.LastIndexOf('/')).Trim('/').Replace('.', '_');
                    string cidWithTimestamp = string.Format("cid:{0}_{1}", cid, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-fffffff")); //append a timestamp to ensure the cid is unique !
                    PageResult = PageResult.Replace(src.Value, cidWithTimestamp);
                    listOfCid.Add(cidWithTimestamp);

                    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                    byte[] originalData = wc.DownloadData(src.Value);

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(originalData);

                    listOfStreams.Add(ms);
                }
            }

            MailAlert.SendRecap(Context.User.Identity.Name, PageResult, listOfStreams, listOfCid);

//end of the 1st bit of code


public static void SendRecap(string connectedUser, string HTMLcontent, List<MemoryStream> listOfStreams, List<string> listOfCid)
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpClient sender = new SmtpClient();

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

                message.From = new MailAddress("recap@test.com");
                message.To.Add(string.Format("{0}@vente-privee.com", connectedUser));
                message.Subject = "Test Recap";
                message.Body = HTMLcontent;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                int i = 0;
                string plainBody = "Plain text content, viewable by clients that don\'t support html";
                AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(plainBody, null, "text/plain");
                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(HTMLcontent, null, "text/html");

                //create the LinkedResource (embedded image)
                foreach (var ms in listOfStreams)
                {
                    ContentType ct = new ContentType();
                    if (listOfCid[i].Contains("gif"))
                    {
                        ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif);
                    }
                    else if (listOfCid[i].Contains("jpg") || listOfCid[i].Contains("jpeg"))
                    {
                        ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
                    }
                    else if (listOfCid[i].Contains("png"))
                    {
                        //contentType = "image/png";
                        ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
                    }

                    LinkedResource imageResource = new LinkedResource(ms, ct);

                    imageResource.ContentId = listOfCid[i];
                    imageResource.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;

                    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imageResource);
                    i++;
                }

                message.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
                message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

                sender.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

When I inspect the received email in smtp4dev, I can see all its parts on the left column "MIME Parts" :

- Unnamed: multipart/alternative (158959 bytes)

  - Unnamed: text/plain (50642 bytes)
  - Unnamed: text/plain (65 bytes)
  - Unnamed: multipart/related (107752 bytes)

    - Unnamed: text/html (50642 bytes)
    - Unnamed: image/gif (4610 bytes)
    - Unnamed: image/jpeg (1908 bytes)
    - Unnamed: image/gif (540 bytes)
    - Unnamed: image/gif (544 bytes)
    - Unnamed: text/html (48466 bytes)

I can even select any of these images, click the Body tab, choose "Save as" and successfully open them in my favorite image viewer.

When I select the "Unnamed: text/html (50642 bytes)" line then Body tab, I can see the HTML source of the email and all the "cid:" (for instance : src="cid:inv_brandLogo_fr_gif_2013-01-04-18-50-34-4569409")

But if I click "Open" in smtp4dev, the email opens up in Internet Explorer without any image.

When IE opens, it shows a warning at the bottom : "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls" and a button "Allow blocked content" which I click, to no avail...

I've read numerous sites/blogs but can't figure out why the embedded images won't show.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: It does not look like you are actually changing the value of the src property in the html code. You are correctly embedding the images in the email, but are you referencing them in the html body of the email?

Comment: If I understood correctly all the examples I read, I need to end up with each src having a unique cid value in the html source which I succeed.

Comment: Like I said, in my final HTML source, I have for instance :

`<img id="ctl00_cphMain_ob_imgClassicPIFBrandLogo" src="cid:inv_brandLogo_fr_gif_2013-01-07-09-07-50-8058158" alt="Classic 10 01" style="border-width:0px;height:73px;width:300px;">`
and smtp4dev shows in the Header tab of the Unnamed: image/gif (4610 bytes) element :
content-type = image/gif | 
content-transfer-encoding = base64 | 
content-id = **<cid:inv_brandLogo_fr_gif_2013-01-07-09-07-50-8058158>**

Comment: I've just successfully used the Base64 method : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1761/embedding-images-in-email/ . So I'll put aside the cid method for now. Wish I could share my code here but the comment length is limited and the formatting is a pain :-/